# Snorby with PostgreSQL installation issue in Mac OS X 10.10.2 (Yosemite)

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails, snort, ruby1.9

Trying to setup [Snorby](https://www.snorby.org) for [Snort](https://www.snort.org) with [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org) on Mac OS X 10.10.2 (Yosemite)

- Snort 2.9.7.2 GRE (Build 177)
- PostgreSQL 9.4.1
- ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-darwin14.1.0]

Here is what happens when I attempt to install it. What’s wrong? Any ideas?

```
$ sudo gem install dm-postgres-adapter
Successfully installed dm-postgres-adapter-1.2.0
1 gem installed

$ sudo bundle exec rake snorby:setup
No time_zone specified in snorby_config.yml; detected time_zone:
America/Chicago
rake aborted!
*cannot load such file -- dm-postgres-adapter*
Tasks: TOP => snorby:setup => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Does that mean that snort database should also be in mySQL?

Comment: well if my snort database in Postgres, but snorby's in mysql will it work then? And why everyone says that Snorby works with Postgres, but no any single guide how to do so?!

Answer (score 0):

Well I've added gem `'dm-postgres-adapter', DM_VERSION` to the Gemfile but it didn't help. People on github say that original snorby isn't working with postgresql... Some say there are a few forks which are kinda postgres-compatible, but I didn't find them ((((